# MySQL query check

Tags: mysql

what is wrong with this query?

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES id, pic0, pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4 FROM table2 WHERE condition1 = 'cond1' AND condition2 = 'cond2' AND age = '18' AND ( weight = '100 - 115 lbs' OR weight = '115- 130 lbs' ) AND hairlength <> 'short'
```

Conditions are for table2. 
I want to insert into table 1 just the rows from table two which meet the conditions set my me after WHERE clause.

Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this -

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, pic0, pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4)
select id, pic0, pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4  
FROM table2 WHERE condition1 = 'cond1' AND condition2 = 'cond2' 
AND age = '18' AND ( weight = '100 - 115 lbs' OR weight = '115- 130 lbs' ) 
AND hairlength <> 'short'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, pic0, pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4)
SELECT id, pic0, pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4
FROM table2
WHERE condition1 = 'cond1' 
AND condition2 = 'cond2' AND age = '18' 
AND ( weight = '100 - 115 lbs' OR weight = '115- 130 lbs' )
AND hairlength <> 'short'
```

Comment: Sachin may also be correct: I don't know off the top of my head whether you need that VALUES statement in your query.

Comment: actually you are right man. My query had VALUES in first line which will give syntax error. Now both our queries are same..;)